# PHP: Difficulty in returning desired values(or data structure) from json_decode

Tags: php, arrays, json

I'm using json_decode on this json data here:

```
issues": [

 {
    "id": "51526",
    "key": "123",
    "fields": {
        "zone": [
            {
                "name": "football",
                "active": true
            },
            {
                "name": "baseball",
                "active": true
            }
        ],
        "icon": {
            "id": "1"
        }
    }
},
{
    "id": "51228",
    "key": "3108",
    "fields": {
        "zone": null,
        "icon": {
            "id": "10"
            }
        }
    }
 ]

}
```

I can properly extract the name data which will be ["football", "baseball"]. However, I also want to capture the null value from the 2nd data set so my data really looks like

```
 ["football", "baseball", null].
```

Basically, I want to look at "zone" and get the value of "name", if "zone" is null then the value is null in order to get this data structure ["football", "baseball", null].

I've tried everything I could think of, but I'm not great at php. Is this possible to do?

Php code:

```
$decoded_array = json_decode($result)->{'issues'};           
            foreach($decoded_array as $issues){                        
            foreach($issues->{'fields'}->{'zone'} as $zn){  
            $nm[] = $zn->{'name'};           
  }
}
```

Comment: Please post some code you use for your task

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this:

```
$data = json_decode($json);
$issues = $data->issues;

$names = array();
foreach($issues as $issue){
  $zones = $issue->fields->zone;
  foreach($zones as $zone){
    if($zone != null){
        $name = $zone->name;
        array_push($names,$name);   
    }else{
        array_push($names,null);
    }
  }      
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When you iterate the json object, check if "zone" is null. If it is, you can add null in your result array.

Pseudo code:

```
Iterate jsonObject 
  if (jsonObject["fields"]["zone"] == null)
  then push_in_array(result,null)
```

Comment: When you add null in your result array, is it simply appending null to the result. Or will it be placed within its original position as seen within the json?

Comment: you can have something like this:
[
"51526"=>"football",
"51526"=>"baseball",
"51228"=>null
]

Essentially, you can bind each value with a unique value. It can be any unique value for each dataset.

Or you can simply bind with array indexes starting from 0.